# Uploading website to live causing problems to plug-in and layout

Tags: plugins, localhost, user-interface

Good day!

I am still learning on how to use wordpress. I have created my website in localhost then wanted to update my live site using my newly created website from localhost. I noticed that when I try to update it, some of my plug-ins produce an error while the plug-in(Beaver Builder which is in current version) is not functioning very well. Some pages, when I try to edit got its row messed up

[image: this is an example]
**(THE LIVE SITE)**

[image]
**(FROM LOCALHOST)**

Sometimes when I try to run it again, it is showing the WSOD(especially to pages that show the above problem). Somehow, some of the pages seems to be working fine but when I try to update it, the loading takes too long but when I refresh the page, the revision did work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to try:

1. Cleaning browser cache
2. Cleaning wordpress cache (https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-clear-your-cache-in-wordpress/)

When you load the page for a first time and then updated code or content, you may need to enforce Wordpress cache cleaning. 
Also you can simply try switch to another theme and then back to your current theme.